# Dynamic WebGL Draw in Game Loop

Tags: javascript, dynamic, webgl

I am fairly new to WebGL and I am working on a 3D game that dynamically generates land around the player. So, I am trying to add vertices to draw in game. Things worked fine, until I started to add this feature, making hundreds of `gl.drawArrays()` calls per frame, which made it super laggy. After having done some research I found that a better way to approach this is to make a huge array containing all of the vertices (each shape separated by degenerate triangles) and then make one `gl.drawArray()` call per frame.

Here is the part of my code that runs on load:

```
function loadGraphics() {
    // ground
    // buffers
    quadVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    vertices = [];
    verticesItemCount = 0;

    quadVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVertexColorBuffer);
    var colors = [
        0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0,
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    quadVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
    quadVertexColorBuffer.numItems = 4;
}
```

Here is the part that runs per frame:

```
function drawGraphics() {
    // draw code for graphics
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clearColor(0.35, 0.4, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);
    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

    // perspective
    var cameraX = camera.x, cameraY = camera.y, cameraZ = camera.z;
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, rotMatrix[1], [1, 0, 0]);
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, rotMatrix[0], [0, 1, 0]);
    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-cameraX/33, -cameraY/33, -cameraZ/33]);

    debug.add("{camera} x:"+camera.x+",y:"+camera.y+",z:"+camera.z+";");
    debug.add("\n{mouse delta} x:"+mouse.x-mouse.prevX+",y:"+mouse.y-mouse.prevY+";");
    debug.add("\n{rm}[0]:"+rotMatrix[0]+",[1]:"+rotMatrix[1]);
    // ground

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVertexColorBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, quadVertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


    // land plots
    vertices = [];
    verticesItemCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < landPlots.length; i++) {
        var oX = landPlots[i].x*3;
        var oZ = landPlots[i].z*3;

        var plotVertices = [
            -1.5+oX,  0.0,  1.5+oZ,  1.0,
             1.5+oX,  0.0,  1.5+oZ,  1.0,
            -1.5+oX,  0.0, -1.5+oZ,  1.0,
             1.5+oX,  0.0, -1.5+oZ,  1.0
        ];

        pushDrawArray(plotVertices, 4);

        for(var j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
            debug.add(" " + renderLandPlotIntersection(landPlots[i], j));
        }           

    }
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, verticesItemCount);
}
function renderLandPlotIntersection(landPlot, side) {
    var x = landPlot.x;
    var z = landPlot.z;

    var lvl = landPlot.level;
    var olvl = null;
    var plot;

    switch (side) {
        case 0: plot =getLandPlot(x-1, z  ); if (plot !== null) olvl = plot.level/66; else return 0; break;
        case 1: plot =getLandPlot(x,   z+1); if (plot !== null) olvl = plot.level/66; else return 0; break;
        case 2: plot =getLandPlot(x+1, z  ); if (plot !== null) olvl = plot.level/66; else return 0; break;
        case 3: plot =getLandPlot(x,   z-1); if (plot !== null) olvl = plot.level/66; else return 0; break;
        default: throw "Land plot intersection drawing: side out of range."; return -1;
    }

    var intersectionVertices = [
        x*3,  lvl,  z*3,
        x*3,  lvl,  z*3,
        x*3,  olvl, z*3, 
        x*3,  olvl, z*3
    ];

    pushDrawArray(intersectionVertices, 4);

    return +1;
}
function pushDrawArray(array, itemCount) {
    if (vertices.length > 0) {
        // degenerate 

        vertices.push(vertices[vertices.length-3]);
        vertices.push(vertices[vertices.length-2]);
        vertices.push(vertices[vertices.length-1]);

        vertices.push(array[0]);
        vertices.push(array[1]);
        vertices.push(array[2]);

        verticesItemCount += 2 ; 
    }

    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesItemCount*4, array);
    verticesItemCount += itemCount;
}
```

I started using `DYNAMIC_DRAW`, though I don't really know how to use it. `verticesItemCount` marks how many vertices are in the `vertices` array.

`gl.drawArrays()` returns this error:

> [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-060B7ED8]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1 localhost/:1 WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.

How can I fix this code to not cause an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what I did. I made the vertex position array longer than my vertex color array, so it was trying to access something out of bounds. The fix is to keep the vertex color array the same length as the vertex position array.